# Opening different file on IOError

Tags: python, python-2.7

I've written a python script that wants to write logs to a file at /var/log/myapp.log. However, on some platforms this doesn't exist, or we might not have permission to do that. In that case, I'd like to try writing somewhere else.

```
def get_logfile_handler():
    log_file_handler = None
    log_paths = ['/var/log/myapp.log', './myapp.log']
    try:
        log_file_handler = logging.FileHandler(log_paths[0])
    except IOError:
        log_file_handler = logging.FileHandler(log_paths[1])

    return log_file_handler
```

The above code may work, but it seems far from elegant - in particular, trying a different file as part of the exception handling seems wrong. It could just throw another exception!

Ideally, it would take an arbitrary list of paths rather than just two. Is there an elegant way to write this?

Comment: I believe the `tempfile` module may solve the problem https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/tempfile.html

Comment: Loop over your `log_paths` until you get one that doesn't raise `IOError`. If you get to the end of the list without finding a valid name, log to stderr, or die with an appropriate error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simply use a loop such as:

```
def get_logfile_handler():
    log_file_handler = None
    log_paths = ['/var/log/myapp.log', './myapp.log']
    for log_path in log_paths:
        try:
            return logging.FileHandler(log_path)
        except IOError:
            pass

    raise Exception("Cannot open log file!")
```

HTH

Comment: A `return logging.FileHandler(log_path)` would save a few lines of code and return the first valid handler instead of the last.

Answer (score 1):

There is, as @PM-2's comment suggests, no need to reference each possible path individually. You could try something like this:

```
def getlogfile_handler():
    log_file_handler = None
    log_paths = ('/var/log/myapp.log', './myapp.log') # and more
    for log_path in log_paths:
        try:
            log_file_handler = logging.FileHandler(log_path)
            break
        except IOError:
            continue
    else:
        raise ValueError("No log path available")
    return log_file_handler
```

The `else` clause handles the case where the loop terminates without finding a suitable log_path value. If the loop breaks early then (and only then) the `return` statement is executed.

It's perfectly OK to use exceptions for control flow purposes like this - the cases are exceptional but they aren't errors - the only real error occurs when no path can be found, in which case the code raises its own exception that the caller may catch if it so chooses.

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_logfile_handler( log_files ):
    log_file_handler = None
    for path in log_files:
        try:
            log_file_handler = logging.FileHandler(path)
            break
        except IOError:
           pass

    return log_file_handler
```

This may solve your problem. You can define locally/globally instead of passing as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

As a possible solution if you want to avoid handling exceptions you can check the Operating System you are on by using the `platform` module and then choose the required path. Then you can use the `os` and `stat` modules in order to check permissions.

```
import platform
import os
import stat

...

#the logic goes here

...
```